# Undefined method response when using let and subject in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I tried to write some tests for the "show" action in Rails API

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AirlinesController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @airline = FactoryGirl.create(:airline)
      get :show, id: @airline.id
    end

    it "should return the airline information" do
      airline_response = json_response
      expect(airline_response[:name]).to eql @airline.name
    end

    it {should respond_with :ok}
  end
end
```

The test passed. However, when I try to use `let` and `subject` like this

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AirlinesController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #show" do
    let(:airline) {FactoryGirl.create(:airline)}

    subject {airline}

    before(:each) do
      get :show, id: airline.id
    end

    it "should return the airline information" do
      airline_response = json_response
      expect(airline_response[:name]).to eql airline.name
    end

    it {should respond_with :ok}
  end
end
```

It showed "NoMethodError undefined method `response' for ..."

This makes me confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `subject`. The subject of a controller spec is the controller, not a model object. Just remove the line that sets `subject` and you shouldn't get that error any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
it {should respond_with :ok}
```

I assume this line takes the `subject` and makes a `response` call.
The recommended syntax is:

```
it "returns 200" do
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Or maybe your `json_response` helper method is using `subject.response` instead of `response`.